# Seeking workflow to build cloud optimized tif?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, bigtiff

By its definition, a cloud optimized GeoTIFF is a regular GeoTIFF file, aimed at being hosted on a HTTP file server, whose internal organization is friendly for consumption by clients issuing.

Based on the [gdal doc](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/CloudOptimizedGeoTIFF), I can create a cloud optimized tif by running

```
gdal_translate in.tif out.tif -co TILED=YES -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW
```

on a file **with existing overviews**.

Because of the size of my tif files, I would like to avoid making my tif file "cloud optimized" **after** building the pyramid in order not to duplicate the writing.

Is it possible to use the -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES when I build my pyramids with **gdaladdo** or is it necessary to run it in an additional step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear you can't really write cloud optimised GeoTIFF directly if overviews are needed. In the document that you cited the structure of such GeoTIFF is

1. TIFF / BigTIFF signature
2. IFD (​Image File Directory) of full resolution image
3. Values of TIFF tags that don't fit inline in the IFD directory, such as TileOffsets, TileByteCounts and GeoTIFF keys
4. Optional: IFD (Image File Directory) of first overview (typically subsampled by a factor of 2), followed by the values of its tags that don't fit inline
5. Optional: IFD (Image File Directory) of second overview (typically subsampled by a factor of 4), followed by the values of its tags that don't fit inline
   ...
6. Optional: IFD (Image File Directory) of last overview (typically subsampled by a factor of 2N), followed by the values of its tags that don't fit inline
7. Optional: tile content of last overview level

   ...
8. Optional: tile content of first overview level
9. Tile content of full resolution image.

When you create a new GeoTIFF with gdal_translate it writes the components 1, 2, 3 (if needed), and 9, in that order. I am not actually sure if 3 will be written after 2 or 9 but anyway, when you create overviews with gdaladdo they will be written after the component 9 because there is no space before it. Only once all the components exist and their sizes are known they can be re-organized into optimal order.

Answer (score -1):

what i usually do is:

```
#build a vrt for fast processing
gdalbuildvrt input.vrt input.tif

#do the warp/any other operations on the vrt and save to vrt again
gdalwarp -tr 10 10 -r near -overwrite input.vrt input_warped.vrt

#translate to gtiff with compression
gdal_translate -of GTiff input_warped.vrt ouput.tif -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co TILED=YES -co PREDICTOR=2

#create overviews
gdaladdo -r average ouput.tif 2 4 8 16
```

without the `gdal_translate` the ouput EU wide raster at 10m is almost 300gb, with the compression it's less than 1gb.